# android horizontallist view

Tags: android, listview

How to add a horizontal listview inside a listview.I have source code for horizontal listview.
I want to add it in listview so that each row in list is scrollable.

Any example would be great help.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I would recomend you to use scrollview with tablelayout mutch better.

Comment: this isn't answer and just a comment